# dexguard obfuscation class reference not found

Tags: dexguard

on dexguard obfuscation the referenced classes not find error is thrown during dexguard release build.

> **can't find referenced class com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference**

please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

DexGuard prints out warnings about missing dependencies, just like a compiler.

If your application relies on the class, you need to make sure that the corresponding library is listed in your project's dependencies.

If your application doesn't really need the class, you can suppress the warning with

```
-dontwarn com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference
```

in your DexGuard configuration.